# Indexing issue when manipulating Series of boolean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having what I think it an indexing problem with my DataFrame filtering.

I have a logic where I will apply different masks on a DataFrame and, instead of restricting the DataFrame directly I build my mask according to my custom logic.

```py
# df as an input (which has already been filtered and I think it messed with it's indexing

from pandas import Series


mask = Series([True] * df.shape[0]) 

if some_filter is not None:
    col_mask = df['aCol'] == some_filter
    mask = mask & col_mask
```

Here if I a look at:

```
mask.shape
col_mask.shape
```

They are identical before the last line.

After this last line `mask.shape` indicates almost the double of lines, I think that it is because series are indexed and the indexes don't match, the boolean operation actually fill in the blanks.

I can think about a few workaround around this. I would like to have the proper to do this or approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already said it, your dataframe does not has the range index, e.g. `df.index == [0,1,3,5]`. You can just pass a np.array:

```
# list also works
# mask = [True] * len(df)
mask = np.array([True] * len(df))
```

Or pass `df`'s index to the Series constructor to align it:

```
mask = pd.Series([True] * len(df), index=df.index)
```

Then your following code would work:

```
if some_filter is not None:
    col_mask = df['aCol'] == some_filter
    mask = mask & col_mask
```

Comment: Seems to be a perfect answer ;-)